# In R bookdown how do I set the default code output background color

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

My R bookdown book with gitbook style renders with the code output in a gray box.  I would like to change it to be a white box with a black border.  I have found posts showing how to set the color for a specific block but not how to set the default.   I think I need to add a css file like this:

```
--- 
title: x
author: clueless
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::gitbook: 
    css: "style.css"
---
```

but I a don't know where to go from here.  I know very little css. So clues for the clueless would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using only CSS

The previous answer is correct for the CSS rule but the selector must be more specific for a `gitbook()` format. This a matter of [CSS specificity](https://specifishity.com/).

Using a browser inspector, you can get a sense of the selector you need to use to override default CSS style set by `gitbook`.

This simple css will replace background and add a border

```css
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal pre {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-color: #000;
}
```

You put in as you do in `style.css` and use the `css` argument of `bookdown::gitbook` in `index.Rmd` or in `_output.yml`depending of which you are using.

This will pick up the CSS.

I think you could also use `!important` to have the most specify on `pre` with

```css
pre {
    background: #fff !important;
    border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
    border-color: #000 !important;
}
```

(*Edit after comment above*)

### Using knitr feature

Another way would be to use `class.source` and `class.output`
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-styling.html

This would allow you to set a specific class for your output and target this class in your CSS.

it would require to apply the chunk option to all code chunk using

```r
knitr::opts_chunk$set(class.output = "custom-output")
```

Then you could use `pre.custom-output` to target only the code chunk output part, using one of the two syntax above (full selectors or !important)

Comment: Thank you!  This is much closer.  Your code styles both the code and output the same.  Is there a way to limit it to only applying this to the output?  I inspected the html and the code is tagged with <code class="sourceCode r"> and the output is tagged with <pre>. Is there a way to NOT apply your change to the "sourceCode r" chunks? In other words, I want to keep the default style for the code and use your code for only the output.

Comment: I added a solution that would ease for you the CSS rule to write to target only the output part of code chunk

Comment: Thank you so much!  The CSS with the opts_chunk$set() works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippets are styled with the `<pre>` tag. If you've figured out how to link your CSS file, adding the below to it should give you the results you want:

For example:

```css
pre {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-color: #000;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<body>
<pre> 
Hello this is code 
This is more code. 
You could have this could be whatever you want.
Monty Python!
</pre>

</body>
```

Feel free to tweak the numbers and values to fit your need.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Your CSS makes sense. Unfortunately, I must be doing something wrong with the YAML header because R Markdown is not using the file.

Comment: Where have you stored the file? Ideally, it should be under `./css/style.css`.

Comment: It is in the rstudio project folder.  When I build the book a copy of the CSS file is put into the _book directory. I made a css directory and put the style sheet in there and it still is not applying it when I look at the page.