# Cross-reference code chunks in `bookdown` similar to figures, tables, and equations

Tags: css, r-markdown, bookdown

When I am writing with `bookdown`,
I would like to be able to refer to a code chunk in the text.
Presumably, this would require a two-fold solution:

- Index each target code chunks numerically
- Add href anchors to the indices so that I can refer to them in the text

With the help from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65597432/2271797) and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48924780/2271797),
I was able to piece together a solution for the first part.

Inside `style.css`:

```css
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal {
  counter-reset: counter-rchunks;
}

.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal div.section div.sourceCode {
  padding-right: 5em;
}

.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal div.section div.sourceCode pre.demor {
  counter-increment: counter-rchunks;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal div.section div.sourceCode pre.demor::after {
  content: '[' counter(counter-rchunks) ']';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5em;
  color: rgb(48, 63, 159);
}
```

Inside one of the `bookdown` chapters:

````
    ```{r class.source = "demor"}

    cars |>
      dplyr::slice_head(n = 3)

    ```
````

The result, once knitted, would look like this:

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone could help me complete the solution
so that I could cross-reference code chunks within the text.
For example,

> As shown in chunk 1, ...

in which the "1" would be a hyperlink to where the actual chunk is located on the page.

Comment: I am glad someone is trying to do the same, any luck since you posted this @chunyun?